# Python send emails with corresponding attachments

Tags: python, class, outlook, email-attachments

I have a desktop folder with 3 XLSX files: `ID1.xlsx`, `ID2.xlsx`, `ID3.xlsx`

I can use the following code to loop through a list of 3 email addresses and send individual emails to each address, but it attaches all XLSX files in the folder.

**Expected Result:** I want to attach `ID1.xlsx` to the first email and send, `ID2.xlsx` to the 2nd email and send, and finally `ID3.xlsx` to the 3rd email and send.

```
email_addresses = ['test1@test.com', 'test2@test.com', 'test3@test.com']

class EmailsSender:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

    def send_email(self, to_email_address, attachment_path):
        mail = self.outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = to_email_address
        mail.Subject = 'Report'
        mail.Body = """Report is attached."""
        if attachment_path:
            mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment_path, Type=olByValue)
        mail.Send()

    def send_emails(self, email_addresses, attachment_path=None):
        for email in email_addresses:
            self.send_email(email, attachment_path)

attachment_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Test\*.xlsx'
email_sender = EmailsSender()
email_sender.send_emails(email_addresses, attachment_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You will need to reference the file name with email so switch to [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).*

*Example*

```
email_addresses = {'test1@test.com': 'ID1.xlsx',
                   'test2@test.com': 'ID2.xlsx',
                   'test3@test.com': 'ID3.xlsx'
                   }

attachment_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Test'


for email, file in email_addresses.items():
    print(email, attachment_path + file)
```

Comment: Thank you! I created a dictionary with the email and file, but when I edit my code above, it says "file not defined". Any thoughts? Could you demonstrate the "for" loop being used in my code above?